# Rhino Mock 3.6 Repository Expected #0, Actual#1

Tags: rhino-mocks, rhino

I'm using Rhino Mock 3.6 Repository and Nhibernate. But I'm getting ExpectationViolationException Expected#0, Actual #1. I've spent two days on it. I don't know what i'm doing wrong. Here is my code. I'm getting error on mockRepository.Save(user) line.

```
        var username = "abcdef";
        var mocks = new MockRepository();
        var validationResults = new ValidationResults();
        IDataQuery query = mocks.StrictMock<IDataQuery>();
        UserRepository mockRepository = mocks.StrictMock<UserRepository>(query);
        var user = mocks.StrictMock<User>();

        user.FirstName = "javed";
        user.LastName = "ahmad";
        user.UserName = "abc";
        user.Password = "password";
        user.Email = "nadeem@test.com";
        user.IsActive = true;
        user.CreatedBy = 1000000;
        user.CreatedDate = DateTime.Today;
        user.ModifiedBy = 1000000;
        user.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Today;

        Expect.Call(user.Validate()).Return(validationResults);
        mocks.ReplayAll();

        mockRepository.Save(user);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Thanks
Imran

Answer (score 7):

You're using a StrickMock which means the only calls to be considered valid are the calls you set Expectations for.  Since you didn't set an Expectation that `Save` would be called, you're getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

Normally this means RhinoMock expects you to call user.Validate() once, but you call the method twice. You can either check that you call the method only once or change

> Expect.Call(user.Validate()).Return(validationResults);

to

> Expect.Call(user.Validate()).Return(validationResults).Repeat.Twice();

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be mocking everything even the sut i.e. userrepository
you should be setting up mocks on interfaces that will be used inside the userrepository.  you will need to pass these in to the userrepository to override their default behaviour somehow.

You need to decide what you actually want to test.

The code above implies the following to me

```
class UserRepository
{
  public void Save(IUser user)
  {
    validationResult = user.Validate();
    if (validationResult==null)
    {
      dal.Save(user);
    }
  }
}
```

That's just a guess, but the point is the code you currently have should only be mocking the user if your intention is to test that the validate method is called within the userrepository.save method

Comment: you also may want to check out the AAA syntax for rhino mocks it's far easier to understand